# Событие по клику на кнопку JQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:

```
var ajax;
var user_id = $('#userid').html();
var message = $(".send").val();

$(".btn").click ( 

function send_chat() { 

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            refresh_chat(); 
                $('.send').val('');
        }
    }

    ajax.open("GET", "../action/chat_send.php?user="+user_id+"&message="+message, true);
    ajax.send();

} 

);
```

При клике на btn ничего не происходит, этот код я переделывал, раньше все работало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

P.S. Функция refresh_chat() загружает все сообщения из файла chat_send.php, а в файле chat_send.php - код отправки в бд сообщения, ошибок в нем нет.

Comment: вы консоль откройте и ошибки гляньте. имя функции у вас излишнее. Дак и коли вы уже подключили jquery, то уж напишите просто `$(".btn").click(function(){ $.get(url, function(){ refresh_char(); $(".send").val('');}); })` а не вот эту портянку кода

Comment: Спасибо, помогло) У меня такой вопрос: а как с помощью Вашего кода выводить данные, получаемые из файла, к которому обращается код? В моем длинном коде данные из файла записываются в responseText, и я его вывожу. Я надеюсь, понятно описал

Comment: `$.get(url, function(text){...})`

Comment: Все, понял, спасибо)